# Web Page DOM rending speed decrease with time and make browser freeze

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-devtools, handlebars.js

Web page structure
PHP, JS, Handle Bars and Firebase event for real-time updations.

When web page load first time works fine. After some time about 15-20 (possibly a lot of data change in dom when firebase realtime event happened) page starts to down it working. Uneventalluy leads to browser freeze. I have used the chrome dev tool to find the reason for the issue but unable. Looking for some guidelines and suggestions to debug this issue. Track what is causing this issue.

[image]

Dev tool images

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could check for the memory consumption of the current tab

Comment: Please give us information on how to help you with your issue. Right now all we can say to you is: _Use your dev console and debug it using performance-tab_

Comment: @cloned ok I will share some more details some of the dev tools recording

Comment: @TuanTran yes memory consumption increase and also CPU consumption goes to 100%. According to the window task manager.

Comment: you might have memory leak somewhere in your code